# MySQL full-text search result relevancy

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am trying to search my table for some mobile phones and am trying to get the results via Full-text search. My query is:

```
SELECT id,itemid,title,MATCH(title) AGAINST 
    ("SAMSUNG GALAXY S3" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) as score 
    FROM `deals`WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST 
    ("SAMSUNG GALAXY S3" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ORDER BY score desc;
```

The results i get are shown in the image below:

[image: Search Result]

**What i expect is the second result to come up on top as it is the exact match, but it doesn't**. Can somebody please correct me on what i might be doing wrong here.

Thanks.

**Edit** Results in boolean mode
[image: Results in boolean mode]

Comment: What is the result [`IN BOOLEAN MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) ?

Comment: @bpgergo - here's the result - http://imgur.com/xhIbl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid "S3" is too short token to be considered to be a word by the full text search. 
See relevant section of the docs (the default minimum word length is 4 characters) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len

**EDIT** you can verify this by searching for e.g.:

```
"SAMSUNG GALAXY S360"
```

Comment: Yes, when i search for something like "Samsung Galaxy SIII", it works. Thanks a ton for helping me. Seems i need to find a way to address these kind of searches. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you can set 2 in `ft_min_word_len`, that should work for ""SAMSUNG GALAXY S3"

Comment: In that case i will have to rebuild the index, will check if this helps.